# vim colorscheme to highlight modifications since last commit?

Tags: git, vim, version-control, mercurial

In vim, what I want to do is to highlight all the modifications I have done since the last commit (I personally use mercurial), either using two colors, or a darker and a lighter version of the same colorscheme  for the old and new contents, respectively. I don't care about syntax highlighting coz the document is in latex, so mostly plain text. Any ideas?

PS: basically I want something like vimdiff in the same buffer that I'm doing the editing...does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[vim-signify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify) seems to be exactly what you want: you get colored signs in the gutter, showing added/removed content.

Comment: close, but not quite. It only `signifies` which lines are modified, but not really `diff` the two versions in colors. A good start though, if I can look into the vimscript to find out whether the `diff` thing is easy to do. Thanks.

Comment: there exists a feature request that is exactly what I'm after though on the `vim-signify` issue page. https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify/issues/32

Answer (score 0):

I know [quickfixsigns](https://github.com/tomtom/quickfixsigns_vim) can show the modified/added lines in the gutter. I can say it really works well with git but it's supposed to work with mercurial (according the doc).

If you modify the file outside vim and then open it in vim, the changes made outside vim will show in the gutter as well. I guess this means it's relying on your CVS diff as you seem to want.